# How to assign a dynamic array of pointer returned from a function, to a variable?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dynamic-arrays

Please have a look at the following code

```
    Vehicle ** damagedVehicles(Vehicle **vehicles, int size)
    {
        Vehicle **damaged = new Vehicle *[size];

        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            int d = vehicles[i]->damage;

            if(d>=35)
            {
                damaged[i] = vehicles[i];
            }
        }

        return damaged;
    }

int main()
{
Vehicle **damagedVehicles = damagedVehicles(vManager->getList(), vManager->getCount());
}
```

As you can see, my attemt in the main is not working. How can I assign that array of pointers to a variable?

Comment: No, we can't see. What exactly is not working?

Comment: What's vManager? It's not declared anywhere..

Comment: Post more code and specific what you have problem with?

Answer (score 2):

Rename the variable so it doesn't clash with the name of the function?

```
Vehicle **myDamagedVehicles = damagedVehicles(vManager->getList(), vManager->getCount());
```

Comment: I had a test, it's caused by variable name conflicting with function damagedVehicles name.

Comment: wow! Yes, Thanks a lot Pubby!! Good to know C++ clash with function names and variable names as well!! o_O